# Generically asserting aspect service calls to lower layer with Mockito

Tags: java, mockito, aspect

Looking for a generic way to assert that a call to an aspect services method makes a call to a lower level service call by the same name.

Our application uses OSGI and aspect service where there are several implementations of the same interface with each implementation calling through to the lower layers, and likely doing some post processing. For example...

```
public interface ConfigService {
    public List<String> getConfigurations();
}

public class ConfigServiceImpl implements ConfigService {
    private volatile ConfigDAO dao;

    @Override
    public List<String> getConfigurations() {
       List<String> configs = dao.getConfigurations();
       // do something with configs
       return configs;
    }
}

public class ConfigDAO implements ConfigService {
    @Override
    List<String> getConfigurations() {
       // database calls
       return configs;
    }
}
```

I would like to come up with a generic method, something along the lines of `verifyCallsDelegate(configService, mockConfigDao, "getConfigurations");`, that would allow me to write a bunch of one liners testing call through behavior instead of

```
configService().getConfigurations();
verify(mockConfigDao).getConfigurations();
```

This is a contrived example and I would likely like to take things a step further and assert that the value returned from `mockConfigDao.getConfigurations()` was what was returned from `configService.getConfigurations()` but once I get past getting the simplest test to work I will add that kind of smarts.

Can anyone suggest an implementation or like technique for my ```verifyCallsDelegate```` method above.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want to achieve? I understand your question but don't see what it is you want to test. It seems like you want to test if all implementations follow a given architecture design which would be better suited for static analysis tools like SonarQube with a custom rule

Comment: As we use aspect services all over the place, sometimes 3/4 deep I was looking to get some code reuse out of testing that AspectX.getY() calls through to ServiceX.getY(). My ```verifyCallsDelegate``` method above has the kind of signature I would like, taking in a handle to the aspect service, a handle to the service implementation, and a string name for the method to assert is called through.